# Cash register in js

Tags: javascript

What i'm doing wrong? Function enters infinite loop but it shouldn't, it should keep subtracting. My most current trouble is why its not subtracting.

```
    // Create an object which hold the denominations and their values



    while(i<obj1.containers.length || obj1.kusur !== 0){

        var ttt=Math.floor(obj1.kusur/obj1.containers[i]);


        if(obj1.kusur>obj1.containers[i]){
            for(var j=0;j<ttt;j++){

                ind = obj1.initial.indexOf(obj1.containers[i]);
                denomination = obj1.banknote[ind];
                obj1.kusur -= obj1.containers[i];
                temp += obj1.containers[i];
                obj1.kusur= parseFloat(obj1.kusur.toFixed(2));
                temp = parseFloat(temp.toFixed(2));

                console.log(obj1.kusur+" => "+temp+" => "+obj1.containers[i]+" => "+i);

            }

        //console.log(i);
        if(i===obj1.containers.length || obj1.kusur === 0){

            break;

        }
            i++;

        }



        /*if(obj1.kusur==temp || obj1.kusur<obj1.containers[i]){

            arr1[0] = denomination;
            arr1[1] = temp;

            change.status = "OPEN";
            change.change.push(arr1);

        }*/

    }

  }
```

Here's a [pen](https://codepen.io/codename11/pen/GBQzde). Result are in console. It stops subtracting near the end. Why it works at start then don't work near the end?

Edited code that is working:

```
while(i<obj1.containers.length || obj1.kusur !== 0){

    var ttt=Math.floor(obj1.kusur/obj1.containers[i]);


    if(obj1.kusur>obj1.containers[i]){
        for(var j=0;j<ttt;j++){

            ind = obj1.initial.indexOf(obj1.containers[i]);
            denomination = obj1.banknote[ind];
            obj1.kusur -= obj1.containers[i];
            temp += obj1.containers[i];
            obj1.kusur= parseFloat(obj1.kusur.toFixed(2));
            temp = parseFloat(temp.toFixed(2));

            console.log(obj1.kusur+" => "+temp+" => "+obj1.containers[i]+" => "+i);

        }

    }
    else{

        i++;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that it gets stack at container being $.05 instead of $.01. Your i++ is inside the for loop inside your while loop. Basically the i++ isn't getting triggered so it keeps looping on the same i value (i = 6).

Comment: Thanks. It's been whole day working on this problem so i didn't catch much sleep or eat. Thanks for noticing.